# Finding values of a matrix with specific distribution

Tags: matrices, statistics, algorithms

Suppose I have a MxN matrix.I want to choose values such that: 
1. If I choose the values of each column, they have the same distribution (Dist(c1) = Dist(c2) = ... = Dist(cN)) 
2. If I choose the values of each row, they have the same distribution (Dist(r1) = Dist(r2) = ... = Dist(rM) 
3. All of the M*N values have a truncated Gaussian distribution with specific mean and standard deviation.

Is it possible? If so, I was wondering how I can approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a first positive answer with matrices having their entries in the form $c_id_j,$ i.e., rank-one matrices :

$$\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\ \vdots \\ c_M \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}d_1&d_2&\cdots&d_N\end{pmatrix}$$

where the $c_k$s obey a certain distribution $D_1$, and the $d_{\ell}$s, another one, $D_2$.

Edit : This case is by no means anecdotal : it is the case where distributions are independent. In all other cases (rank > 1), I think you will have non-independent distributions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I know the distribution of all of the elements (mean and std of M*N devices). How can I determine mean and std of distribution of columns and rows?

Comment: I think that you must take into account the fact that there is a correlation : in fact you have marginal distributions with their characteristics (mean, std) and you need the equivalent characteristics for the so-called "joint-distributions. See my little "Edit".

Comment: thanks for your response. I still have problem and did not understood it very well. My knowledge is not very deep in this area. So, you mean, if D1 and D2 are are dependent, the rank will be 1? How do you define the dependency in distributions (would it be the same type, mean, and std?)? I also added a condition #3 to my question, how does you answer change based on that?

Comment: What I meant is that " you can write the matrix under the form I have given" (which is the same as saying  "the rank is 1") $\implies$ D1 and D2 are independent". In fact, instead of "independent" (which cannot be tested experimentally) one should say "uncorrelated" i.e. with experimental correlation coefficient $\approx 0$.